# How to create class class object and function class object in python

Tags: python

in java we can have objects of class and Method. how we can achieve same in python.

Example (in java)
"""Class cls=Class.forName("Test.class");
Method method = Test.class.getMethods()[];"""

Comment: There are reflection functions such as `type()`, `dir()`, `isintstance()`, `callable()`, `getattr()`, `setattr()` and others. But there is no such Java'ic thing like class of class, because everything in python is an object (even classes)

Comment: look at meta programming I think. what do you mean by function class object

Answer (score 1):

You can create the class by reflection.

And with inspect built-in module, you can get methods:

```py
import inspect


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "default"

    def method_1(self):
        pass


my_second_way_to_call_class = globals()["MyClass"] #reflection
my_third_way_to_call_class = MyClass # assignation of the object def

instance_1 = MyClass()
instance_2 = my_second_way_to_call_class()
instance_3 = my_third_way_to_call_class()

method_list = inspect.getmembers(instance_1, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
print(method_list)
```